# set default java version to graalvm in ant deployment

Tags: graalvm

So I think i'm stuck in dependency hell here, but I can't figure out how to force ant to use the graalvm JVM in the deploy. I've been given a build.xml script that has javascript in it and i'm getting the 'since nashorn removed' etc error message.

My $JAVA_HOME is set to the /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm.versionDetail/Contents/Home directory, and this directory/bin is in the path variable.

The output of java -version is:

```
java version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19, mixed mode, sharing)
```

How do I tell ant to default to the GraalVM version?